# How to clone an object in ArrayList (RecyclerView)?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a clone of an object in ArrayList used by RecyclerView, i've yet extended my entity with Clonable but when i edit the cloned object even the original one is modified.

What would be the correct way to clone/duplicate an object in RecyclerView?

Entity:

```
public class Prodotti implements Serializable, Cloneable {
private final String descProdotto;
private double qta;
private int turno;
private String codice;
private String time;
private String codOP;
private String state;
private String pre;
private ArrayList<Varianti> variants = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

}
```

Entity Varianti:

```
public class Varianti implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    String descrizione;
    private String codice;
    transient BitmapDrawable drawable;
    private String state;
    public String pre;
    public String qta;

    public Varianti(String descrizione, String codice, BitmapDrawable drawable, String state, String pre, String qta) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.codice = codice;
        this.drawable = drawable;
        this.state = state;
        this.pre = pre;
        this.qta = qta;
    }

    @NonNull
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
    ArrayList<Prodotti> listProdotti = new ArrayList<>();

    Prodotti prodotto = listProdotti.get(position);

    @Override
    public void onClickDuplicate() {
        try {
            Prodotti productDuplicate = (Prodotti) prodotto.clone();
            productDuplicate.setState("A");
            listProdotti.add(productDuplicate);
            adapterProdotti.notifyItemInserted(listProdotti.size() - 1);
            recyclerComanda.scrollToPosition(listProdotti.size() - 1);
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Then when a RecyclerView item is swiped pass the position to a modify Dialog where i'm able to make some edits on the object.

**EDIT:**

By looking deeper i've found that the problem persists only when there are some child elements in the entity (variants array) else the clone works as it has to.

So if my entity has any object in variants and it's cloned then if i add a new variant in one of the two object both will get it..

Comment: Please remind yourself about [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: @GhostCat i've made an edit, hope it could be useful

Comment: Let's step back. You have read a book or tutorial on how cloning works? And you see, one big issue of creating a DEEP clone is: EVERYTHING that your to-be-cloned object "owns" ...needs to be cloneable as well. So, most likely, your `Varianti` class can't be cloned. Did you implement that one to be cloneable? Long story short: cloning is bad, and when you actually decide to use it, then: you have to KNOW what you are doing. Just because a concept exist doesnt mean A) it is easy to use or B) it should be used.

Comment: @GhostCat `Varianti` is Cloneable, i've just added it's code, i have to implement the clone function as it is a required function (Like in the app a user can create a plate with multiple variables then he must be able to clone that cause the same plate could have all variations plus one new)

Comment: Hint: NEVER edit the question to include the answer. Either write a self answer, or maybe edit/enhance the answer you got and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ocasin pointed out the cloned `Prodotti` was still pointing to the original `Varianti` lists.

I was able to solve the issue by clearing the `Varianti` list from the cloned entity and by cloning the `Varianti` list itself and setting it in `Varianti` list of the cloned entity.

```
        try {
            Prodotti productDuplicate = (Prodotti) prodotto.clone();
            productDuplicate.setState("A");

            productDuplicate.setVariantsList(new ArrayList<Varianti>());
            ArrayList<Varianti> varianti = (ArrayList<Varianti>) prodotto.getVarianti().clone();
            productDuplicate.setVariantsList(varianti);
            
            listProdotti.add(productDuplicate);
            adapterProdotti.notifyItemInserted(listProdotti.size() - 1);
            recyclerComanda.scrollToPosition(listProdotti.size() - 1);
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think when you clone your `Prodotti`-Object, the reference to the `variants` ArrayList is cloned with it, so the `variants` field in the cloned `Prodotti`-Object points to the same list as the `variants`-field of the origninal `Proddotti`-Object.

I would recommend using a copy-constructor instead of `clone()` and then handle the copiing of the `variants`-field manually;

Comment: Yea you are right the cloned one was still pointing at the original `variants` list, so i've made an edit to the question with a temporary solution :)